# How-To: Creating Angular/Bootstrap btn-checkboxes in a repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create a grid (table with ng-repeat) where in each row, there are 4 columns of buttons. Ideally the buttons would be checkboxes, such as the Angular/Bootstrap **btn-checkbox**, so that they would have an on and off mode, which I would set from my database-derived data in the C# code that would feed the Angular page.

[image]

The problem I'm having is that I don't really know how to check the state of those btn-checkbox controls in my controllers.js when the Apply/Save button gets clicked, so I can save the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

I'm using eval to create scope variables within $scope.buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/tekmtn/dnfhnLex/3/

```
app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.records = [1,2,3,4];
    $scope.buttonSets = [1,2,3,4];
  $scope.buttonsPerSet = ["Added", "Changed", "Closed"];

  $scope.buttons = {};

  $scope.toggleButton = function(recNum, setNum, btnText) {
    var field = "$scope.buttons." + "btnRec" + recNum + "_setNum_" + setNum + "_" + btnText;
    var value = eval(field);
    if(!value) {
        eval(field + " = 1;");
    } else {
        eval(field + " = 0;");
    }
  }

  $scope.isActive = function(recNum, setNum, btnText) {
    var field = "$scope.buttons." + "btnRec" + recNum + "_setNum_" + setNum + "_" + btnText;
    var value = eval(field);
    if(value == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }

  $scope.save = function() {
    // send $scope.buttons through web service.
  }
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <table class='table table-striped'>
           <thead>
            <tr>
          <th>Record</th>
          <th ng-repeat="setNum in buttonSets">
            Button Set {{setNum}}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="recNum in records">
          <td>Record {{recNum}}</td>
          <td ng-repeat="setNum in buttonSets">
            <button ng-repeat="btnText in buttonsPerSet"
                    class='btn btn-default btn-xs' type='button'
                    uib-btn-checkbox
                    btn-checkbox-true="1"
                    btn-checkbox-false="0"
                    ng-click="toggleButton(recNum, setNum, btnText);"
                    ng-class="{'active':isActive(recNum, setNum, btnText)}">
              {{btnText}}
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    {{buttons}}
    <br /><br />
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Cancel</button>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Apply</button>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that possible with Bootstrap 2.3.2? (We have yet to upgrade in my shop to BS3.)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tekmtn/dnfhnLex/7/ Updated the jsfiddle to use angular bootstrap 0.8.0 (last ui-bootstrap to support bootstrap 2.3.2)

Comment: if you check out that link - you'll see it works with bootstrap 2.3.2, just need to use ui-bootstrap 0.8.0

Comment: Ok. I've poked it, prodded it, showed it to the guys on my team... and we love it. It's !@#$ing rad. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Also - Greetings to you, from me, another Missoulian!

Comment: Glad I could help out @PKD - Wish there was some internal messaging - i'd ask more. Curious about Seattle :)